# SSRS Bar Chart by Group with Separate Categories

Tags: reporting-services, charts, ssrs-2008, ssrs-grouping

I have built quite a few SSRS reports with Charts, but I have been a new chart that I need to build and I am not sure if it is possible or how to create it? Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this with a standard **Column** chart:

[image]

Consider a simple DataSet like this:

[image]

The corresponding chart would be set up similar to this:

[image]

Most important things to note are that the **Series** group is based on *Person* and the **Category** group is based on the category field like *Contact %*.

This gives results similar to your requirements:

[image]

You'll have a few further refinements to make, e.g. making sure percentage values are displayed, and that **Data Labels** are displayed, but this should give you the basic structure to build on.